# Checking multiple conditions before returning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to return `mycollection.first.user.name`, but `mycollection` or `mycollection.first` may be nil. The following code is ugly, but works:

```
if mycollection && mycollection.first && mycollection.first.user
  mycollection.first.user.name
end
```

What is the Ruby way?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Rails, it adds a method to `Object` called `try` which might help:

```
mycollection.try(:first).try(:user).try(:name)
```

That will call `first`, `user`, and `name` in sequence, but if any of the values in the chain is `nil`, it will just return `nil` without throwing an exception.

If you're not using Rails, you can define it yourself very easily:

```
class Object; def try(method,*args,&block); send(method,*args,&block); end end
class NilClass; def try(method,*args,&block); nil; end end
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people are not too keen on try(), but it is certainly one approach that you might like.

```
name = mycollection.try(:first).try(:user).try(:name)
```

name will be nil if anything is nil, or will return the value of name.

Additionally, you may want to refactor your model, such that you can call something like this:

```
item.user_name

class ItemClass
  def user_name
    user.try(:name)
  end
end
```

with item being the first in the collection.

```
name = if mycollection && item = mycollection.first
  item.user_name
end
```

Comment: A bit too late =) Looks like Alex has a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Ruby, you could do:

```
if mycollection && mycollection.first.respond_to?(:user)
  mycollection.first.user.name
end
```

That's because if `mycollection` is an empty array, `mycollection.first` will return nil:

```
irb(main):002:0> nil.respond_to?(:user)
false
```